# ArrayList toArray() conversion doesn't let you use lenth()?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;
class Ball{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(new Integer(1));
        al.add(new Integer(2));
        al.add(new Integer(3));
        Object a[]= al.toArray();

        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Contents are  :"+ a[i]);
        }
}}
```

So I created an ArrayList and added a couple of elements to it. Then used toArray method and got object array a. However if I use `i<a.length()` instead of `i<a.length`, I get an error. What I don't understand is that if `length()` is a method, what is `length`?

Secondly why can't I output ArrayList elements using a for loop?

```
for (int i=0; i<al.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Contents are  :"+ al[i]);
        }
```

(over here using al.length() as well as al[i] gives an error)

Comment: `length` is a public field for arrays. The method `length()` doesn't exist.

Comment: You also can't access `ArrayList` elements using array notation. arrays != `ArrayList`

Answer (score 6):

First, arrays have a `length` field which is `final` and `int` type. Arrays do not have a `length` method.

This is noted in [Java Language Specification. Chapter 10. Arrays.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) (emphasis mine):

> 10.2. Array Variables
>
> Once an array object is created, **its length never changes**. To make an array variable refer to an array of different length, a reference to a different array must be assigned to the variable.
>
> 10.3. Array Creation
>
> An array creation expression specifies the element type, the number of levels of nested arrays, **and the length of the array for at least one of the levels of nesting. The array's length is available as a `final` instance variable `length`.**

To access to the elements of an array, use `[index]`:

```
System.out.println(a[index]);
```

Second, [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) doesn't have a `length` method, but [`size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--).

To access to the elements of an `ArrayList` by inde, use the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) method:

```
System.out.println(al.get(index));
```

Note that an `ArrayList` **is not** an array, it is a class **that uses an array** as container to hold the elements it will store and will add, remove, search and create a new array if it needs to hold more elements that it can.

To go through all the elements of an array or a `List` (interface implemented by `ArrayList`), it is better to use the enhanced `for` loop:

```
for (Object o : a) {
    System.out.println(o);
}
for (Object o : al) {
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a **field** named `length`.

Lists have a **method** named `size()`.

To access the third element of an array you use this:  `someArray[2]`

To access the third element of a List, you use this: `someList.get(2)`

To summarize: Lists and Arrays are very different.

Please consider reading the [documentation for the List interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (which ArrayList implements), where you can learn everything you need to know about Lists and their methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why one is a method and the other a field: The size of an array is determined when it's created so a `final` field, i.e. one that can't be changed, is safe to be made `public` and accessed by users of the class. On the other hand, collections' sizes can change. Classes that implement `Collection` or `List` also have a field for size, but this field can't be `final`. So it has to be made `private` and a getter method has to be used to enforce the encapsulation. Otherwise anyone could just do something like `myArrayList.size = -5;` and break the implementation.