# How can I get the size of an array, a Collection, or a String in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, collections

What are the different ways that I can access the length of an array, a collection (`List`, `Set`, etc.), and a `String` object?  Why is it different?

Comment: This is, for the most part, an attempt to create a canonical answer for all of the Java-specific questions about accessing the size of these three things.

Comment: May I ask what inspired you to create this question/answer?

Comment: I still didn't understand why this Question and Answer (and comment too), from same user???

Comment: @AnkitLamba it looks useful for me, but I still want to know the motivation for this question/answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23729508/1079354), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965500/length-and-length-in-java), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9652732/1079354), and a handful of others which only answer one of the few fragments to getting the size of a `String`, `Collection`, or array.  Kind of felt like Java needed a canonical answer to what seems to be a commonly asked question.

Comment: It looks good, but for more info for beginners, you should add a section about `ArrayList` vs `arrays`, explaining that they're not the same (or point to another Q/A where this is explained in deep).

Comment: That might not be a bad Q&A to write up.  Give me something like...10 minutes to see if I can find something that's reliable and answers that general question, or drum something up for it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Abridged:

For an array:  use **`.length`**.

For a `Collection` (or `Map`):  use **`.size()`**.

For a `CharSequence` (which includes `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder`):  use **`.length()`**.

---

### Arrays

One would use the **`.length` property** on an array to access it.  Despite an array being a dynamically created `Object`, the mandate for the `length` property is defined by the [Java Language Specification, §10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3):

> An array is created by an array creation expression [(§15.10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) or an
>   array initializer [(§10.6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).
>
> An array creation expression specifies the element type, the number of
>   levels of nested arrays, and the length of the array for at least one
>   of the levels of nesting. **The array's length is available as a final
>   instance variable `length`.**
>
> An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for
>   all its components.

Since the length of an array cannot change without the creation of a new array instance, repeated accesses of `.length` **will not change the value**, regardless of what is done to the array instance (unless its reference is replaced with a differently sized array).

As an example, to get the length of a declared one-dimensional array, one would write this:

```
double[] testScores = new double[] {100.0, 97.3, 88.3, 79.9};
System.out.println(testScores.length); // prints 4
```

To get lengths in an *n*-dimensional array, one needs to bear in mind that they are accessing one dimension of the array at a time.

Here's an example for a two-dimensional array.

```
int[][] matrix
      = new int[][] {
                         {1, 2, 3, 4},
                         {-1, 2, -3, 4},
                         {1, -2, 3, -4}
    };

System.out.println(matrix.length); // prints 3 (row length or the length of the array that holds the other arrays)
System.out.println(matrix[0].length); // prints 4 (column length or the length of the array at the index 0)
```

This is important to make use of, especially in the case of [jagged arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271540/java-jagged-array); the columns or rows may not always line up all the time.

### Collections (`Set`, `List`, etc.)

For every object that implements the `Collection` interface, they will have a **method** called [**`size()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size()) with which to access the overall size of the collection.

Unlike arrays, collections are **not fixed length**, and can have elements added or removed at any time.  A call to `size()` will produce a nonzero result if and only if there has been anything added to the list itself.

Example:

```
List<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
shoppingList.add("Eggs");
System.out.println(shoppingList.size()); // prints 1
```

Certain collections may refuse to add an element, either because it's `null`, or it's a duplicate (in the case of a `Set`).  In this case, repeated additions to the collection will not cause the size to increment.

Example:

```
Set<String> uniqueShoppingList = new HashSet<>();
uniqueShoppingList.add("Milk");
System.out.println(uniqueShoppingList.size()); // prints 1
uniqueShoppingList.add("Milk");
System.out.println(uniqueShoppingList.size()); // prints 1
```

Accessing the size of a `List<List<Object>>`* is done in a similar way to a jagged array:

```
List<List<Integer>> oddCollection = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
}};
oddCollection.add(numbers);
System.out.println(oddCollection.size()); // prints 1
System.out.println(oddCollection.get(0).size()); // prints 3
```

<sup>*:  `Collection` doesn't have the `get` method defined in its interface.</sup>

As an aside, a `Map` is not a `Collection`, but it also has a [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#size()) method defined.  This simply returns the number of key-value pairs contained in the `Map`.

### `String`

A `String` has a **method [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())** defined.  What it does is print the number of characters present in that instance of the `String`.

Example:

```
System.out.println("alphabet".length()); // prints 8
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget `CollectionUtils.size()` from the [commons library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#size(java.lang.Object)), its null safe so you don't have to null check beforehand.

Comment: Shame that it can't handle `CharSequence`s.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it different?

I'll try to answer this part, since it doesn't seem to be covered in the other answers.

The method on a `CharSequence` (including `String`) is called `.length()` because a sequence has a length. "Length" is a sensible word to use for a sequence, because it has a start and an end, and you can measure how far apart they are; just like you can measure the distance between two ends of a stick to get the "length" of the stick.

The method on a `Collection` is called `.size()` because not every collection is a sequence with a start and an end. Imagine having a collection of two thousand different [stamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stamp_collecting); you would say that the "size" of your collection is 2,000, but you would not say that the "length" of your collection is 2,000. The word "size" is more natural for things that aren't measured from start to end. It happens that some collections like `ArrayList` *do* represent a sequence where it makes sense to talk about their length, but the method is still named `.size()` because that method name is inherited from the `Collection` interface; it would be strange to add *another* method named `.length()` for sequential collections, which would do the same thing as the inherited `.size()`.

Arrays are sequences, so they have lengths. However, arrays are a low-level feature of the language; they aren't instances of an "array" class that could declare a `.length()` method, so therefore `.length` isn't a method. Syntactically it looks like accessing a field, but it isn't a field; an expression which gets the length of an array is compiled to the [bytecode instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) `arraylength`. The distinct bytecode instruction for an array's length corresponds with the distinct syntax for it.