# Does array.length give you the number of elements in the array, or the size of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering, does `array.length` give you the number of elements in the array, or the size of the space inside the array that you declared. For example if I declare the following array:

```
int [] Array = new Array[10];
```

and then add one element to the array, will `array.length` be 1 or 10?

Also is there any way to find the other number. For example if `array.length` corresponds to the number of elements in the array, is there any way to find the space inside of the array?

Comment: Try it and find out :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the number of elements in the array" being different from its length; the array will start out with 10 zeroes, all of which are "elements" of the array.

Comment: [Perhaps this can enlighten you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730092/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-a-collection-or-a-string-in-java)  (I do go over the nuance of it a bit there.)

Comment: Java arrays are zero indexed, the addressable range of the array will be [0-9], just so you are aware

Comment: You can't "add elements to arrays". Arrays have a fixed size which can never be changed.

Answer (score 4):

10. The length of the array is its capacity.

Answer (score -1):

It's 10. Length returns capacity of array regardless of it's elements.